# 'security policies' error when trying to run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler, homebrew

I have recently been having a lot of trouble with my rubies.

Now whenever I try and run `bundle install` on my projects I get the following error:

```
 bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-        1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:172:in `security_policies': uninitialized constant Gem::Security::Policies (NameError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:175:in `<class:CLI>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<module:Bundler>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have tried reinstalling rubies, I have tried `rvm get head` and `gem update --system`

I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing OpenSSL, through `rvm package` and `brew install`.

And I have tried completely imploding RVM and starting again, but none of this seems to work. This seemed to happen after I shifted to Mavericks.

Does anybody out there have an idea what might be happening? I have been at this for 3 days...

#### Edit:

I am having the same issue with all these rubies:

- 1.9.3
- 2.0.0-p195
- 2.0.0-p247
- 2.1.0-preview1

Comment: do you have `~/.bundle/config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running bundle install on a new rvm gemset running Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0 on OSX Mavericks, I was receiving the same error:

```
gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:172:in `security_policies':    uninitialized constant Gem::Security::Policies (NameError)
```

Running 'brew install openssl', then 'rvm reinstall 2.0' worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using brew...

1. Run `brew doctor` to check the current state and perform any steps it recommends.
2. Run `rvm list` and note which versions of ruby are installed. Remove the offending ruby version with `rvm remove 2.0.x` where 'x' is the minor revision you are working with, or run `rvm remove 2.0` to remove them all.
3. Now upgrade to the latest rvm, `rvm get stable`.
4. Let rvm install dependencies automatically by running `rvm autolibs enable`. This will allow rvm to install whatever it needs during the ruby installation, including openssl. It will use brew, as I am assuming here, but will also use fink or macports if they are installed instead. In the past I have had problems with brew and macports both installed.
5. Install the latest ruby via rvm, `rvm install 2.0`.

Bundler should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the --trust-policy=[] option with bundle install?
To Apply the Rubygems security policy named policy, where policy is one of HighSecurity, MediumSecurity, LowSecurity, or NoSecurity. 
More - http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html